# Read from and write to CSV file using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file like below

```
a,v,s,f
china,usa,china and uk,france
india,australia,usa,uk
japan,south africa,japan,new zealand
```

I'm trying to get output like below, by removing repeated words in each row

```
       a             v        s            f
0  china           usa   and uk       france
1  india     australia      usa           uk
2  japan  south africa           new zealand
```

for which I'm doing

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO


data="""a,v,s,f
china,usa,china and uk,france
india,australia,usa,uk
japan,south africa,japan,new zealand"""

df= pd.read_csv(StringIO(data).decode('UTF-8') )


from collections import Counter
def trans(x):
    d=[y for y in x]
    i=0
    while i<len(d):
        j=i+1
        item=d[i]
        while j<len(d):
            if item in d[j]:
                d[j]=d[j].replace(item,'')
            j+=1
        i+=1
    return d

print df.apply(lambda x:trans(x),axis=1 )
```

It works fine as long as I input the data into variable 'data'. But if I want to import that from csv file by doing `data = pd.read_csv("trial.csv")`, it doesn't work. I get an error message saying `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'decode'`. How can I read the data from a CSV file and write output to CSV file using pandas? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Did you do `data = pd.read_csv("trial.csv").decode('UTF-8')`? use the "encoding" parameter instead: `data = pd.read_csv("trial.csv", encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: @tdelaney I tried that too. I got this error `'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 54: invalid start byte`. Does it have anything to do with the starting of my CSV file? It starts with a "!".

Comment: No, the decoder doesn't care about the semantics of the file. It means that its not a utf-8 file and that the bad stuff starts at position 54. It could be utf-16, enoded in some code page, or just plain corrupted.

Comment: @tdelaney That has given a different error. I tried without any encode decode stuff and the error has moved to a different line now. Pointing at `if item in d[j]:`, it has given me `("argument of type 'long' is not iterable", u'occurred at index 0') `

Comment: By default, pandas will try to convert strings that look like nubmers into numbers. If you have columns that are supposed to be numbers, I guess you could detect and skip them.   ...as an aside, you only need the lambda if the incoming parameters need to be converted in some way, `print df.apply(trans,axis=1)`.